# Alert dialog not showing during while loop

Tags: c#, loops, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I set breakpoint on my while loop and the **Show()** part executes but no actual dialog appears on the screen. The app just freezes while looping and eventually an exception occurs. Any ideas? Maybe I should make it async call but how?

```
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tu.TargetBin))
{
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).SetTitle(_warning)
            .SetMessage(
                "Es gibt keine leeren Kanäle! Warten Sie bis ein Kanal leer ist und tippen Sie 'OK'.")
            .SetPositiveButton(_ok,
                delegate
                {
                    tu.TargetBin = Utility.WsHueckmann.GetPackBin(order.DocNo,
                        _orders.First().PackingPlace);
                })
            .Create()
            .Show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific what you are trying achieve here and maybe show some more code as the method where the while loop is implemented in.

Comment: You are overweighting main thread of your app. Why do you use a loop to raise multiple `AlertDialog`? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely should make it async.
Now you just create tons of alertdialogs in the loop and before user even sees the first of them, you got an exception (probably out of memory).
Instead of this you probably need something like:

```
    var ok_pressed = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(_warning, 
     "Es gibt keine leeren Kanäle! Warten Sie bis ein Kanal leer ist und tippen Sie 'OK'.", _ok, _cancel);
    if(ok_pressed) {
           tu.TargetBin = Utility.WsHueckmann.GetPackBin(order.DocNo,
                        _orders.First().PackingPlace);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do you find App.Current.MainPage? How is DisplayAlert defined? I'm not using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: According to your tags in OP, I assume you work with Xamarin.
So you have an instance of Application class there. It has MainPage.
Alternatively you can use your current page if you have reference to it in this function. You need some Xamarin.Page to display alert on it.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/System.String/

Comment: In your activity you have reference to Application.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the tags. It's Mono app.

Comment: Still you do have instance of android's Activity, don't you? There you have property named Application.

Comment: Actually it probably does have to do with Xamain.Forms, sorry.

Comment: @Grisha The OP having the xamarin or the xamarin.android tag doesn't specifically mean he is using Xamarin.Forms. There is a specific xamarin.forms tag for it.

Comment: @Raimo Yes, but originally it had only xamarin tag.

Comment: @bigb055
You can use Show_Dialog class as shown here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71735/how-to-display-a-message-box-or-alert-message-in-c-xamarin-android